# cannot print out [0] data from following html code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Can I just print out [0] from the html ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup("""<div class="couponTable"><div id="tgCou1" class="tgCoupon couponRow"><span class="spBtnMinus"></span><!-- react-text: 67 -->Wednesday Matches<!-- /react-text --></div><div class="couponRow rAlt1 tgCou1" id="rmid20180905WED1"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_JLC.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Japanese League Cup" title="Japanese League Cup" class="cfJLC"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/icon_tv-C661.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="C661-i-CABLE 661 C601-i-CABLE 601" title="C661-i-CABLE 661 C601-i-CABLE 601"></span></span><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div><div class="couponRow rAlt0 tgCou1" id="rmid20180905WED2"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/flag_JLC.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="Japanese League Cup" title="Japanese League Cup" class="cfJLC"><img src="/ContentServer/jcbw/images/icon_tv-C662.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="C662-i-CABLE 662 C602-i-CABLE 602" title="C662-i-CABLE 662 C602-i-CABLE 602"></span></span><img src="/football/info/images/btn_odds.gif?CV=L302R1g" alt="All Odds" title="All Odds"></a></div></div></div>""",'html.parser')

lines=soup.find_all('img')
for line in lines:
    print(line['alt'])
```

Output

```
Japanese League Cup
C661-i-CABLE 661 C601-i-CABLE 601
All Odds
Japanese League Cup
C662-i-CABLE 662 C602-i-CABLE 602
All Odds
```

Expected Output

```
Japanese League Cup
Japanese League Cup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your responses to other people, it appears that you don't want the alt-text of all the images, but only specified ones. The common denominator from the (admittedly small) example you gave is that they share a class. Might this be what you're looking for?

```
lines=soup.find_all('img', class_='cfJLC') 
for line in lines:
    print(line['alt'])
```

Output:

```
Japanese League Cup
Japanese League Cup
```

Comment: Didnt see that class. Good catch ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in lines:
    print(line['alt'])
```

This prints all the details that are available in lines. As you just want the details about **Japanese League Cup** you need to do as follow which will give you the attribute alt from your image.

```
print(line.attrs['alt'])
```

Comment: dear, but all "img" have 'alt', so that why showed all alt output

Answer (score 0):

Get the divs seperately and then get img tags from it.

```
for div in soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "couponRow"}):
    print(div.find_all("img")[0].title)
```